# Calling HttpGet in Background Service but seems doesn't work

Tags: android, background, android-service, http-get

I am tryin to send values with **HttpGet**. The function is in a Service. What i'm trying is when i'm click the button from Activity sending this values,and when my app is ended.It's working fine when app is open i can sending values and see this values with Toast message.When i end app just i can see values in Toast,but when check i see they didn't go to Web Page and then my database.My code follows,

```
public class LocService extends Service {
Timer timer;
Handler handler;
Location location1;
String logId = "";

final static long TIME= 10000;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            location1 = new Location(loc);
            tempVeriler.loc = new Location(loc);//tempVeriler is a class keeps temp values
        }
    };
    boolean gps_enabled = locManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean network_enabled = locManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (tempVeriler.id != null)
        logId = tempVeriler.id;

    if (gps_enabled) {
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
    } else if (network_enabled) {
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
    }
    timer= new Timer();
    handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            giveInfo();
        }
    }, 0, TIME);

}

private void giveInfo() {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (location1 != null) {
                getInternetData();
                Toast.makeText(
                        LocService.this,
                        location1.getLatitude() + " "
                                + location1.getLongitude(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void getInternetData() {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    URI website;
    try {
        website = new URI(
                "http://www.someadress.com/Default.aspx?logID="
                        + logID+ "&latitude="
                        + new Double(location1.getLatitude()).toString()
                        + "&longitude="
                        + new Double(location1.getLongitude()).toString());

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry it's has to be **handler**

Comment: what is is? handler use main/UI thread looper ... all runnable posted to this handler **runs on main/UI thread** ... yet another NetworkOnMainThreadException question ... why you are using handler at all? ... also you will never get the exception if you are swallowing it like `catch (Exception e) {
    }`

Comment: exception's name is NetworkOn **Main** ThreadException not NetworkOnUIThreadException

Comment: I dont know why but with just timer it app is stopped so i found this if you have any other suggestion or link it would be great :)

Comment: What is the guarantee that your onlocationchanged method executed before your timertask. In such cases there is a probable null pointer exception on location1 object. So it is better fire the timer task after onlocationchanged is called.

Comment: i wrote 'if (location1 != null)'

Answer (score -2):

You can not perform any networking task in UI or Main thread, you have to use handler for that purpose. Change your getInternetData() method in this way,

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    URI website;
    try {
        website = new URI(
                "http://www.someadress.com/Default.aspx?logID="
                        + logID+ "&latitude="
                        + new Double(location1.getLatitude()).toString()
                        + "&longitude="
                        + new Double(location1.getLongitude()).toString());

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
}, 500);
```

And please read this [NetworkOnMainThreadException | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Comment: Where? in onCreate? then it will end with NOMTException ... in giveInfo? then why he need a Handler at all?

Comment: i changed inside of getInternetData() but it doesn't sending values when i end the app should i change giveInfo() too?